# bigquery creating timestamp buckets with 15 minutes interval

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I want to achieve this:

**Output**

```
12:00:00 - 12:15:00
12:15:00 - 12:30:00
12:30:00 - 12:45:00
12:45:00 - 1:00:00 .......,
count(orders)
from table
```

I have a timestamp in the data table available (2022-07-05 19:45:00 UTC), I want to achieve #orders with every 15 minutes interval for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Using **RANGE_BUCKET** function, you can create timestamp buckets for each 15 minutes.  Consider below sample query:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS 
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-07-05 00:00:00', '2022-07-05 10:00:00', INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)) `order`
;

SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(intervals[SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(UNIX_SECONDS(`order`), intervals) - 1)]) ts,
       COUNT(`order`) AS orders,
  FROM `sample_table`,
UNNEST ([STRUCT(GENERATE_ARRAY(UNIX_SECONDS('2022-07-05'), UNIX_SECONDS('2022-07-06'), 60 * 15) AS intervals)])
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to output bucket names formatted as a range, a case expression can create bucket names that meet your needs based on each row's timestamp, which you can then group by in order to count the rows in each bucket.

```
WITH
  fake_order_details AS (SELECT "some value" AS order_detail),
  orders AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2023-11-27 00:00:00', '2023-11-28 00:59:00', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) AS order_timestamp
    CROSS JOIN fake_order_details)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(minute FROM order_timestamp) BETWEEN  0 AND 14 THEN FORMAT("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:00:00 - %d-%02d-%02d %02d:15:00", EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp))
    WHEN EXTRACT(minute FROM order_timestamp) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN FORMAT("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:15:00 - %d-%02d-%02d %02d:30:00", EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp))
    WHEN EXTRACT(minute FROM order_timestamp) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN FORMAT("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:30:00 - %d-%02d-%02d %02d:45:00", EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp))
    WHEN EXTRACT(minute FROM order_timestamp) BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN FORMAT("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:45:00 - %d-%02d-%02d %02d:00:00", EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(year FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(month FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(day FROM order_timestamp), EXTRACT(hour FROM
    -- extract hour from a timestamp one hour later
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(order_timestamp, INTERVAL 1 hour)))
    ELSE "Unexpected timestamp"
  END AS order_timestamp_bucket,
  COUNT(*) AS order_count
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_timestamp_bucket
ORDER BY order_timestamp_bucket
```

[image]

Boundary issues may come into play. For example, it might be clearer if your bucket names included the year, month, and day to avoid accidentally aggregating orders from different dates. You might also want to inform your users that the counts include orders up to but not including the ending timestamp in the bucket name.